# Method that fetches rows from database and maps it to a Model class with SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, .net, repository, ado.net

So, I have a project that has a lot of methods that look alike. 
In the below method as you can see it just fetches a bunch of rows from database and maps it to a model class.

In this  case `ParkingSlipDetails` class. 
There are several such methods in the project that do the exact same thing only with a different set of data and a different model class. There is no complicated business logic here. Just pure fetching data and mapping it to a model.

**Something like this:**

```
  public CustomReturn < List < ParkingSlipDetails >> GetAllParkingSlips(int offset, int fetch)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = null;
        try
        {
            List < ParkingSlipDetails > ParkingSlipDetailsList = new List < ParkingSlipDetails > ();
            sqlConnection = (SqlConnection) sqlHelper.CreateConnection(); //sqlHelper is a nugget and not in my control
            sqlConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Constants.GetAllParkingSlips, sqlConnection);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CreatedBy", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = gepservice.GetUserContext().UserId;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OffsetRows", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = offset;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FetchRows", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = fetch;
            var refCountdr = (RefCountingDataReader) sqlHelper.ExecuteReader(cmd);
            var sqlDr = (SqlDataReader) refCountdr.InnerReader;
            if (sqlDr != null)
            {
                while (sqlDr.Read())
                {
                    ParkingSlipDetails ParkingSlipDetails = new ParkingSlipDetails();
                    ParkingSlipDetails.Id = Convert.ToInt32(sqlDr[FileUploadConstants.Id]);
                    ParkingSlipDetails.FileName = Convert.ToString(sqlDr[FileUploadConstants.FileName]);
                    ParkingSlipDetails.FileUri = Convert.ToString(sqlDr[FileUploadConstants.FileURI]);
                    ParkingSlipDetails.PONumber = Convert.ToString(sqlDr[FileUploadConstants.DocumentNumber]);
                    ParkingSlipDetails.UploadDate = Convert.IsDBNull(sqlDr[FileUploadConstants.UploadDate]) ? DateTime.UtcNow: Convert.ToDateTime(sqlDr[FileUploadConstants.UploadDate]);
                    ParkingSlipDetails.FileStatus = (Status)(Convert.ToInt16(sqlDr[FileUploadConstants.FileStatus]));
                    ParkingSlipDetails.ReceiptNumber = Convert.ToString(sqlDr[FileUploadConstants.RecieptNumber].ToString());
                    ParkingSlipDetails.TotalRows = Convert.ToInt32(sqlDr[FileUploadConstants.TotalRows]);
                    ParkingSlipDetails.CreatedBy = gepservice.GetUserContext().UserId;
                    ParkingSlipDetailsList.Add(ParkingSlipDetails);
                }
            }
            return new CustomReturn < List < ParkingSlipDetails >> (ParkingSlipDetailsList);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            LogError("ManageParkingSlipDataAccess", "GetAllParkingSlips", "Error", ex);
            return null
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sqlConnection != null)
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

**I think there is a lot of scope for refactoring here since there is a lot of places where I would repeat :**

```
sqlConnection = (SqlConnection)sqlHelper.CreateConnection(); 
sqlConnection.Open();
```

**and**

```
var refCountdr = (RefCountingDataReader) sqlHelper.ExecuteReader(cmd);

var sqlDr = (SqlDataReader) refCountdr.InnerReader;
if (sqlDr != null) {
  while (sqlDr.Read())    
  {

  }
}
```

**And I also think the looping is repetitive for each method. Each such method has a loop that maps object to `cmd.Parameters`**

How do I separate the looping and mapping? Should I create an extension method on `ParkingSlipDetails` Class that takes `SqlDataReader` and returns an instance of `ParkingSlipDetails`? Even then I will be repeating reader creation and lopping in each model class.

Comment: Why is this not a valid question?

Comment: Tell us more about what the code is exactly supposed to do please.

Comment: Is this your real code?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Updated my question. Please take a look.

Comment: @Heslacher Very close to real code. Why?

Comment: Because we only deal with real code. See the [help] to read why

Comment: @Heslacher I just renamed the model class to hide name of my organization. Other than that, its identical to my real code.

Comment: I honestly do not understand why this question has been downvoted. Isn't this site about code review and refactoring? It's my first day here so please bear with me.

Comment: Then its ok. Hope you will get some good answers. Just be patient because it can take some time to write a review. Btw you shoul change your title to what your code is doing. Stating what you want to achieve just applies to too many questions.

Comment: @Heslacher edited the title. Though I am not sure if this one is better. I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!  I've edited the title to reflect what the code actually does rather than phrasing it as a question.  Unlike many of our sister sites, that's what works best here.

Comment: I think that the best refactoring would be using some simple ORM in your case. I would advise Dapper. You will have twice less code

Comment: @Disappointed I agree 100%. But my organization is totally against ORM. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3):

To quote Mark Seemann from the following article [Small methods are easy to troubleshoot](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/11/18/small-methods-are-easy-to-troubleshoot/)

> Write small methods. How small? Small enough that any unhandled exception is easy to troubleshoot.

Break the function up into smaller more manageable chunks that focus on a single concern as much as possible.

Yes, the net effect of this is a lot of additional functions. They are however easier to read and maintain.

Another benefit of the many small methods it that it would help identify areas that can be generalized into reusable services that help reduce repeated code, allowing it *(the code)* to be more DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)

Lets start with getting the connection

```
private SqlConnection createConnection() {
    var connection = (SqlConnection) sqlHelper.CreateConnection(); //sqlHelper is a nugget and not in my
    connection.Open();
    return connection;
}
```

This can now be wrapped in a `using` block that will dispose of the connection once out of scope

```
using(SqlConnection connection = createConnection()) {

    //...
}
```

While there is nothing wrong with creating the command manually, I personal prefer to let the connection do it rather than newing one. Again wrapping in a `using` block, and populating.

```
//...

using(SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
    command.CommandText = Constants.GetAllParkingSlips;
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add("@CreatedBy", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = gepservice.GetUserContext().UserId;
    command.Parameters.Add("@OffsetRows", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = offset;
    command.Parameters.Add("@FetchRows", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = fetch;

    //...
}
```

That could have also been refactored into its own method, but in my opinion it would have ended up with too many arguments.

This could be fixed with an aggregated value object.

```
public class ParkingSlipQuery {
    public int FetchRows { get; set; }
    public int OffsetRows  { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

for example

```
private SqlCommand createCommand(SqlConnection connection, ParkingSlipQuery query) {
    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = Constants.GetAllParkingSlips;
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add("@CreatedBy", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = query.CreatedBy;
    command.Parameters.Add("@OffsetRows", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = query.OffsetRows;
    command.Parameters.Add("@FetchRows", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = query.FetchRows;
    return command;
}
```

and implemented

```
var query = new ParkingSlipQuery {
    CreatedBy = gepservice.GetUserContext().UserId,
    OffsetRows = offset,
    FetchRows = fetch
};
using(SqlCommand command = createCommand(connection, query)) {
    //...
}
```

The execution of the command and subsequent reader result however can be moved

```
private SqlDataReader executeReader(SqlCommand command) {
    var refCountdr = (RefCountingDataReader) sqlHelper.ExecuteReader(cmd);
    return (SqlDataReader) refCountdr.InnerReader;
}
```

As you have realized by now, you should know what is coming next about building the model to populate the collection.

```
private ParkingSlipDetails getDetails(SqlDataReader reader) {
    ParkingSlipDetails details = new ParkingSlipDetails();
    details.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader[FileUploadConstants.Id]);
    details.FileName = Convert.ToString(reader[FileUploadConstants.FileName]);
    details.FileUri = Convert.ToString(reader[FileUploadConstants.FileURI]);
    details.PONumber = Convert.ToString(reader[FileUploadConstants.DocumentNumber]);
    details.UploadDate = Convert.IsDBNull(reader[FileUploadConstants.UploadDate]) ? DateTime.UtcNow: Convert.ToDateTime(reader[FileUploadConstants.UploadDate]);
    details.FileStatus = (Status)(Convert.ToInt16(reader[FileUploadConstants.FileStatus]));
    details.ReceiptNumber = Convert.ToString(reader[FileUploadConstants.RecieptNumber].ToString());
    details.TotalRows = Convert.ToInt32(reader[FileUploadConstants.TotalRows]);
    details.CreatedBy = gepservice.GetUserContext().UserId;

    return details;
}

private List<ParkingSlipDetails> getDetailsList(SqlDataReader reader, string userId) {
    List<ParkingSlipDetails> detailsList = new List<ParkingSlipDetails>();
    if (reader != null) {
        while (reader.Read()) {
            ParkingSlipDetails details = getDetails(reader);
            details.CreatedBy = userId;
            detailsList.Add(details);
        }
    }
    return detailsList;
}
```

Finally, to avoid null reference errors, the method should try to avoid return `null`. An empty collection is safer to check than a null collection.

This results in refactor looking like

```
public CustomReturn<List<ParkingSlipDetails>> GetAllParkingSlips(int offset, int fetch) {
    List<ParkingSlipDetails> detailsList = new List<ParkingSlipDetails>();
    try {
        using(SqlConnection connection = createConnection()) {
            string userId = gepservice.GetUserContext().UserId;
            var query = new ParkingSlipQuery {
                CreatedBy = userId,
                OffsetRows = offset,
                FetchRows = fetch
            };
            using(SqlCommand command = createCommand(collection, query)) {
                using(SqlDataReader reader = executeReader(command)) {
                    detailsList = getDetailsList(reader, userId);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        LogError("ManageParkingSlipDataAccess", "GetAllParkingSlips", "Error", ex);
        detailsList = new List<ParkingSlipDetails>();
    }
    return new CustomReturn<List<ParkingSlipDetails>>(detailsList);
}
```

The `using` block will handle the closing and disposal of the connect and the other disposable members.

If following explicit dependency principle, it could be refactored further down by delegating the argument values to the caller.

```
public CustomReturn<List<ParkingSlipDetails>> GetAllParkingSlips(ParkingSlipQuery query) {
    List<ParkingSlipDetails> detailsList = new List<ParkingSlipDetails>();
    try {
        using(SqlConnection connection = createConnection()) {                
            using(SqlCommand command = createCommand(collection, query)) {
                using(SqlDataReader reader = executeReader(command)) {
                    detailsList = getDetailsList(reader, query.CreatedBy);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        LogError("ManageParkingSlipDataAccess", "GetAllParkingSlips", "Error", ex);
        detailsList = new List<ParkingSlipDetails>();
    }
    return new CustomReturn<List<ParkingSlipDetails>>(detailsList);
}
```

with the following support methods

```
private SqlConnection createConnection() {
    var connection = (SqlConnection) sqlHelper.CreateConnection(); //sqlHelper is a nugget and not in my
    connection.Open();
    return connection;
}

private SqlCommand createCommand(SqlConnection connection, ParkingSlipQuery query) {
    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = Constants.GetAllParkingSlips;
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add("@CreatedBy", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = query.CreatedBy;
    command.Parameters.Add("@OffsetRows", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = query.OffsetRows;
    command.Parameters.Add("@FetchRows", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = query.FetchRows;
    return command;
}

private SqlDataReader executeReader(SqlCommand command) {
    var refCountdr = (RefCountingDataReader) sqlHelper.ExecuteReader(cmd);
    return (SqlDataReader) refCountdr.InnerReader;
}

private List<ParkingSlipDetails> getDetailsList(SqlDataReader reader, string userId) {
    List<ParkingSlipDetails> detailsList = new List<ParkingSlipDetails>();
    if (reader != null) {
        while (reader.Read()) {
            ParkingSlipDetails details = getDetails(reader);
            details.CreatedBy = userId;
            detailsList.Add(details);
        }
    }
    return detailsList;
}

private ParkingSlipDetails getDetails(SqlDataReader reader) {
    ParkingSlipDetails details = new ParkingSlipDetails();

    details.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader[FileUploadConstants.Id]);
    details.FileName = Convert.ToString(reader[FileUploadConstants.FileName]);
    details.FileUri = Convert.ToString(reader[FileUploadConstants.FileURI]);
    details.PONumber = Convert.ToString(reader[FileUploadConstants.DocumentNumber]);
    details.UploadDate = Convert.IsDBNull(reader[FileUploadConstants.UploadDate]) ? DateTime.UtcNow: Convert.ToDateTime(reader[FileUploadConstants.UploadDate]);
    details.FileStatus = (Status)(Convert.ToInt16(reader[FileUploadConstants.FileStatus]));
    details.ReceiptNumber = Convert.ToString(reader[FileUploadConstants.RecieptNumber].ToString());
    details.TotalRows = Convert.ToInt32(reader[FileUploadConstants.TotalRows]);

    return details;
}
```

Comment: This looks better. I was wondering if ` while (reader.Read()) {` could be moved to `getDetails` method?

Comment: It would require another method. I'll edit

Comment: If I understood this correctly. I will have to create a query class for every model class that needs to be filled from database. That will be a lot of classes right? Is it a general practice?

Comment: @SamuraiJack this was just an example specific to this function. A general or base type could be used as needed. That is why I mentioned some trepidation about going that route in my answer

Answer (score 3):

I think this is where LINQ to Sql would come in handy. A simple method like this:

```
public List<T> getObjects<T>(IDbConnection connection,string tableName,params string[] columnNames)
{
    string query = $@"SELECT {String.Join(",", columnNames)} FROM {tableName}";
    using (var dc = new DataContext(connection))
    {
        return dc.ExecuteQuery<T>(query).ToList();
    }

}
```

would simplify things greatly. For instance using a simple class:

```
public class Company
{
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

you could get a list from the Northwinds database like this:

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=NWind.mdb");
var companyList = getObjects<Company>(conn,"Customers","CustomerID","CompanyName","Address");
```

This requires that your properties be properly typed and that the names match the column names you need(they can be case insensitive though). If conversions are needed you can leverage the `set`ter for that.

Depending on what you need to do with the data, you might find it easier to create a `DataTable` instead of a `List`. This will automatically get the names and the types properly set, while still allowing you to iterate over the data and access any data item you need.

Comment: Cant ensure that property name will always be same as column name :/
Also, I am stuck with ADO.NET. I can use linq but not linq to sql.

Comment: Why can't you use `LINQToSQL`?  It is [part of `ADO.net`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/ado-net-and-linq-to-sql).I would suggest going the DataTable route. Each row is basically like an instance of a class, with the columns as individual properties. You can also use a DataGrid to display the data. This will extend to any set of data without setting up individual classes for each set.

Answer (score 1):

If LINQ-to-SQL and other ORMs are not possible to use in your organization. I would suggest to create a fixable solution that makes things easier for you for future updates. For instance, you could create a new class to handle SQL operations. This class will be a thin layer on top of the existing layer. Then, use it to design new methods that will reduce code redundancy, and recall them from the current ones. Then over the time, you'll see that this new handler will replace the current work, which will make your life easier.

`DataTable` also another approach, but it depends on the server IO and how much data it's going to be processed, which consumes more memory.

for your question, you can do something like this :

```
public IEnumerable<IDataRecord> Reader(string query,  SqlParameter[] parameters = null, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure)
{
    var globalConnection = (SqlConnection) sqlHelper.CreateConnection(); //sqlHelper is a nugget and not in my control

    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(globalConnection.ConnectionString)) // just create this scope, in case you don't want to the global connection to be disposed.
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection) { CommandType = commandType })
    {
        // if there is parameters add them
        if (parameters != null)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < parameters.Length; x++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameters[x]);
            }
        }

        connection.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                foreach (var row in reader)
                {
                    yield return (DbDataRecord)(IDataRecord)row;
                }
            }
        }

    } // only this connection will be disposed
}
```

and then use it like this :

```
public CustomReturn<List<ParkingSlipDetails>> GetAllParkingSlips(int offset, int fetch)
{
    try
    {
        var ParkingSlipDetailsList = new List<ParkingSlipDetails>();


    SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[]
    {
        new SqlParameter{ ParameterName = "@CreatedBy", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Value = gepservice.GetUserContext().UserId},
        new SqlParameter{ ParameterName = "@OffsetRows", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Value = offset},
        new SqlParameter{ ParameterName = "@FetchRows", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, Value = fetch}
    };



        var reader = Reader(Constants.GetAllParkingSlips, parameters);

        foreach(var row in reader)
        {

            var pSlips = new ParkingSlipDetails();

            for(int x =0; x < pSlips.GetType().GetProperties().Length; x++)
            {
                var column_name  = row.GetName(x);
                var column_type  = row.GetFieldType(x);
                var column_value = row.GetValue(x);

                // for columns that don't have identical naming with the model's properties 
                if(column_name.Equals(FileUploadConstants.FileURI, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    column_name = "FileUri";
                }
                else if(column_name.Equals(FileUploadConstants.DocumentNumber, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    column_name = "PONumber";
                }
                else if(column_name.Equals(FileUploadConstants.RecieptNumber, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    column_name = "ReceiptNumber";
                }
                else if(column_name.Equals(FileUploadConstants.UploadDate, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    column_value = Convert.IsDBNull(sqlDr[FileUploadConstants.UploadDate]) ? DateTime.UtcNow: Convert.ToDateTime(sqlDr[FileUploadConstants.UploadDate]);
                }                   
                else if(column_name.Equals("CreatedBy", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    column_value = gepservice.GetUserContext().UserId;                      
                }

                    // Use refelection to set the values & use Convert.ChangeType() to convert the data reader value to the property's datatype. 
                    pSlips.GetType().GetProperty(column_name).SetValue(pSlips, Convert.ChangeType(column_value, column_type), null);                                                        


            }


            ParkingSlipDetailsList.Add(pSlips);
        }


        return new CustomReturn<List<ParkingSlipDetails>> (ParkingSlipDetailsList);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        LogError("ManageParkingSlipDataAccess", "GetAllParkingSlips", "Error", ex);
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        // there is no connection in this scope, since it's already disposed within Reader() method.

        //if (sqlConnection != null)
        //sqlConnection.Close();
    }
}
```